# I have 2 problem when I write the command: sudo apt update

Tags: command-line, upgrade, updates, sudo, vpn

```
E: Malformed entry 4 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (absolute Suite Component)\
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Comment: Please post the output of the command `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`